# $f^{(3)}(x) h$ was sucked in big O

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

When I develop the finite difference formula with Taylor, I obtained $$\frac{f(x + 2h) - 2f(x+h) + f(x)}{h^2} = \frac{f''(x) h^2 + f^{(3)}(x) h^3 + O(h^4)}{h^2} =  f''(x) + f^{(3)}(x) h + O(h^2) = f''(x) + O(h)$$

Can you explain why the term $f^{(3)}(x) h$ was sucked in $O(h^2)$ and then changed to $O(h)$?

Comment: Two terms wer dropped in the final equality, and the first was only $O(h)$ which is a superset of $O(h^2)$ as $h \to 0.$

Comment: @coffeemath I am starting doing maths. Could you make a full answer with more details? I don't understand your answer yet.

Comment: "why the term $f^{(3)}(x) h$ was sucked in $O(h^2)$" -- It wasn't. In $f''(x) + f^{(3)}(x) h + O(h^2)$ I see a term $f^{(3)}(x) h$ and another, completely separate term $O(h^2).$

Comment: @DavidK I may be wrong, but I think OP is confused about the final term in the string of equalities, in which the $O(h^2)$ has been dropped, and replaced by a single $O(h)$ term.

Comment: @coffeemath That's definitely part of the confusion too, which is why I didn't comment on the "and then" part (which actually does happen).

Comment: @DavidK Yes, your answer should clear it up for the OP -- it addresses the concerns well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start here:

$$ f''(x) + f^{(3)}(x) h + O(h^2).$$

In your context, $x$ is treated as a fixed quantity whereas $h$ is small,
so $f^{(3)}(x) h$ is effectively a constant times $h$.
A constant times $h$ is just about as pure an $O(h)$ term as you can get.

Writing $f^{(3)}(x) h$ as $O(h)$ we have

$$ f''(x) + O(h) + O(h^2).$$

Now since we're doing big-O of small $h,$ the $O(h)$ term dominates the $O(h^2)$ term. Example: $2h \in O(h)$ and $5h^2 \in O(h^2)$ but $2h + 5h^2 \in O(h).$
In general adding any $O(h^2)$ function to any $O(h)$ function gives you an $O(h)$ function, so we really just have

$$ f''(x) + O(h).$$